# Return the value from Task.Run

Tags: c#, xml, async-await

I am loading an XML file using async/await but cannot work out how to return the value 'xe' from the Task.Run. How do I return this value from within the task shown in the code below?

```
 try
        {                
            Exception exceptionOut = null;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //inside
                try
                {

                    XElement xe = XElement.Load(filePath);
                }
                catch (Exception exceptionIn)
                {                        
                    exceptionOut = exceptionIn;
                }
            });            

            if (exceptionOut != null)
            {
                throw exceptionOut;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //show the error
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Well, you should better use `XElement.LoadAsync`method and forget `Task.Run`

Comment: @SirRufo I also saw this in the documentation but I do not have this method as an option. I am running the latest Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @James why not?

Comment: @TomW The LoadAsync is not in the dropdown list for the XElement class??

Comment: @James it's [part of the standard library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.loadasync). Did you import `System.Xml.Linq`?

Comment: @TomW Yes, I have using System.Xml.Linq in my class. Is there anything else that I may not have done?

Comment: @TomW XElement.LoadAsync is only available on .NET Core 2.0+.

Comment: @ckuri I checked and my machine has 2.1 and 3.1 installed. I cannot find any example of the LoadAsync being used on SO to follow as a guide.

Comment: Your project must be .NET Core 2 or 3 project in order to use it. You can’t use .NET Core in a .NET Framework project.

Comment: @ckuri damn, so it is. Unusual for an -Async method in an old library to be locked only to a recent version, most of them have been around for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this is what you want:

```
try
{
    XElement xe = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return XElement.Load(filePath);
    });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //show the error
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `var xe = await Task.Run(() => XElement.Load(filePath));`.